# Sweet Alert - Button ID

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

This is probably going to be really simple - so sorry!

Currently, I have the below:

```
<button>Hey, click me!</button>
<script>$("button").click(function() {
swal("Success Message Title", "Well done, you pressed a button", "success")
});</script>
```

And it works.

But, I want to make the button an ID so like `<button id="1">Click me</button>` and this then would run the below:

```
<script>$("button(1)").click(function() {
swal("Success Message Title", "Well done, you pressed a button using button 2", "success")
});</script>
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<script>$("#mySuperIdValue").click(function() {
swal("Success Message Title", "Well done, you pressed a button using button 2", "success")
});</script>
```

Comment: It says I need to wait 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<button data-id="1">Hey, click me 1!</button>
<button data-id="2">Hey, click me 2!</button>
```

JS:

```
$("button").click(showMsg);

function showMsg(){
  let id = $(this).data('id');
  swal("Success Message Title", `Well done, you pressed a button using button ${id}`, "success");
}
```

Here's the Codepen: https://codepen.io/richjava/pen/gObowNK?editors=1010